# Calculate Nth number in supertable of two numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Two tables of numbers `a`and `b` are written and merged together in ascending order and duplicates are removed. Now the question is to find `nth` number in this supertable better than `O(n)` complexity .

```
Limits 

1<=A, B<=1000

1<=N<=1000000000
```

here is my implimentation , but it is `O(n)` , can anyone suggest better complexity algorithm ?Thanks !

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

long long int min(long long a, long long b){
    if(a<b) return a;
    else return b;
}

long long int get( long long int a,  long long int b,  long long int count) {
    long long int val = 0,i;
    long long int nexta = a;
    long long int nextb = b;
    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        val = min(nexta, nextb);
        nexta = val < nexta ? nexta : (nexta + a);
        nextb = val < nextb ? nextb : (nextb + b);
    }
    return val;
}


int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while(t--){
        long long int a,b,n;
        cin >> a>> b>> n;
        cout << get(a,b,n)<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example:**
A=3, B= 5

Table of A = 3 , 6 , 9 , 12 ,15 ,18 and so on

Table of B =5 , 10 , 15 , 20 and so on

After Merging : 3, 5, 6, 9 ,10 , 12 ,15 ,15, 18, 20 and so on

Remove Duplicates : 3 , 5 , 6, 9 , 10 , 12 , 15 , 18 , 20 and so on

For N= 2 , 2nd element of the supertable is 5

Comment: This is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is tables `A` and `B` arbitrary or and generated like in your example, that is, with equal value added on each step?

Comment: @Petr yes sir , their tables are merged

Comment: What do you exactly mean saying "tables"? You mean arithmetic progression?

Comment: @Petr  yes sir, like multiplication tables in school

Comment: You have a cycle every `A*B=15` to know which table/index to use.

Comment: This is a problem from SPOJ. http://www.spoj.com/problems/UJ01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right that the arays `A` and `B` are specified as following:

```
A[i] = a*i
B[i] = b*i
```

then you can get at least `O(log N)` solution by applying binary search.

Consider some value `x`. Will it be beyond your `n`th element or not? You need to determine how much elements from united sequence is before `x`. It is done easily: from `A` there are `x/a` elements, from `B` there are `x/b`, but oops --- we have counted common elements two times. There are `x/d` common elements, where  `d` is least common multiply of `a` and `b`, so let's subtract `x/d`. So if `x/a + x/b - x/d>=n`, then `x` is at least `n`th element, otherwise it is before.

Now the binary search code goes as (pseudocode)

```
l = 0
r = a * n + 1
d = lcm(a,b)
while r-l>1
    m = (r+l)/2
    cnt = m/a + m/b - m/d
    if cnt >= n
        r = m
    else l = m
your answer is r
```

Maybe even `O(1)` solution is available